# setgpstimestamp when launching camera with an intent

Tags: android, camera, gps, timestamp, exif

I've launched a camera activity with an intent, is there a way I can use the setgpstime in th camera code source ? I want to include a gps timestamp in the exif data, here is what I did and it's not working :

```
 long time = (currentBestLocation.getTime())/1000;
 exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(time));
```

I divided the time i got from my location by 1000 because gettime() is in milliseconds while time in the setgpstime in the camera code source is in seconds.
It's not working also without the division by 1000.

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: I get the alert "This file does not have the correct gps information "

Comment: For those who still have that problem, I copied what they did in the camera source code and it worked like a charm ! Here is the link :
https://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/source/browse/geopaparazzilibrary/src/eu/geopaparazzi/library/camera/CameraActivity.java?spec=svn3377732aa863ac749b8ac0d7bd404fad23b682ba&r=3377732aa863ac749b8ac0d7bd404fad23b682ba